# Format Phone Number Real-Time using NBAsYouTypeFormatter

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, libphonenumber

I have searched all over the place and I have seen many solutions to this, but most of it are really being "hackish" and error prone.

I am trying to format the phone number on UITextField using the libPhoneNumber iOS Class NBAsYouTypeFormatter.

However, I couldnt find a proper way of using it.

Below is my attempt. (From this thread [Phone number format ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22092689/phone-number-format-ios))

```
      var asYouTypeFormatter = NBAsYouTypeFormatter(regionCode: "US");

func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if textField == phoneTextField {
        if range.length == 0 {
            textField.text = asYouTypeFormatter.inputDigit(textField.text + string);
        }
        else if range.length == 1 {
            textField.text = asYouTypeFormatter.removeLastDigit();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This code really detect `range.length` and *it doesnt take into account that if the user **select one or more character** and then type*.

If the user does that, it will resulted in it not being type.

Have anyone found a more elegant method to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if textField == phoneTextField {
        if range.length == 0 {
            textField.text = asYouTypeFormatter.inputDigit(textField.text + string);
        } else {
            // take the resulting string after the replacement
            var resultString = textField.text.replacingCharacters(in: range, 
                    with: replacementString)
            // prepare the string to be usable by the NBAsYouTypeFormatter
            resultString = String(string.characters.filter { "01234567890+".characters.contains($0)
            // set the result on the text field 
            textField.text = asYouTypeFormatter.inputString(resultString);
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Note: I'm writing in objective C, I didn't test the Swift syntax, but the logic of this solution works for me;

This is my Objective-C working code:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    NSString *resultString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    // This is to let the user clear the text field
    if ([resultString isEqualToString:@""]) { return YES; };

    NBAsYouTypeFormatter *formatter = [[NBAsYouTypeFormatter alloc] initWithRegionCode:[[NSLocale currentLocale] countryCode]];

    NSCharacterSet *allowedPhoneCharacterSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"+0123456789"];

    resultString = [[resultString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                            [allowedPhoneCharacterSet invertedSet]]
                           componentsJoinedByString:@""];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        textField.text = [formatter inputString:resultString];
    });

    return NO;
}
```