# Phone number format from country code on iOS

Tags: ios, swift3, libphonenumber

I need to display phone number format as placeholder in **UITextField**. How can I do that?

For country selection I'm using below mentioned library and it provides me country flag and country code against user selected country.

https://github.com/NikKovIos/NKVPhonePicker

After selecting a country I need to display phone number format for that selected country and on submission of that phone number I have to validate the phone number.

I also find that third party (**PhoneNumberKit**) which is inspired by google's libphonenumber but it is for validating, it do not provide expected phone number format against country code. Below is the link.

https://github.com/marmelroy/PhoneNumberKit

**Update 1:**
Tried this and getting **Generic parser error**

```
let phoneNumberKit = PhoneNumberKit()

do {
    let phoneNumber = try phoneNumberKit.parse("+921230123456")
}
catch {
    print("Generic parser error")
}
```

**Update 2:**
Updated code, still getting exception

```
let phoneNumberKit = PhoneNumberKit()

do {
    let phoneNumber = try phoneNumberKit.parse("1230123456", withRegion: "FR", ignoreType: false)
    let formatedNumber = phoneNumberKit.format(phoneNumber, toType: .international)
    print(formatedNumber)
}
catch {
    print("Generic parser error")
}
```

Comment: Please take a look at the section [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And this can also be relevant.  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @RickBronger I already read this and my question is also valid, please don't discourage without trying to understand the question. This question was not related to your skill set, maybe that's why you couldn't understand. Otherwise i asked a very straight forward question and asked for suggestion to my problem and shared my findings with community. 
Also before posting i double checked that if someone have any solution or way to this problem.

Comment: I didnt see any effort in your question to solve your problem. Neither a code snippet that you are stuck at a point where we can help. Your asking for someone to write code for you that is not how stackoverflow works in my opinion.

Comment: @RickBronger We always need a direction to put effort to do something, i couldn't find that way till now. It is not necessary post every try that is not leading in the right direction. See below answer and comments, you may find some effort on my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who wanna do the same thing, I used two different 3rd parties to achieve the functionality.

1. [NKVPhoneNumber](https://github.com/NikKovIos/NKVPhonePicker)
2. [SHSPhoneComponent](https://github.com/Serheo/SHSPhoneComponent)

**NKVPhoneNumber** is used to select country code, i've modified it a bit a introduced `phone_format` in the Meta Data. Once selected a country from the list it return a `Country` object which includes `Code, Extension, Flag and format_placeholder`

**SHSPhoneComponent** then use that `format_placeholder` for validation of the format.

```
import SHSPhoneComponent
import NKVPhonePicker

@IBOutlet weak var phoneTF: SHSPhoneTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var phoneFlag: NKVPhonePickerTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var lblCountryCode: UILabel!

//MARK: - NKV callback delegates

func countriesViewController(_ sender: CountriesViewController, didSelectCountry country: Country) {
    //

    phoneTF.formatter.setDefaultOutputPattern(country.formatPattern)
    phoneTF.text = ""
    phoneTF.placeholder = country.formatPatternPlaceHolder
    countryCode = "+\(country.phoneExtension)"

    lblCountryCode.text = countryCode
}
```

**Note:** I've converted **NVKPhoneNumber** to **Swift 4.0**,

Comment: the countriesViewController function is never called in my project. And I already put phoneFlag.phonePickerDelegate = self. Do I need to configure something else?

Comment: @AndréVicente I have the same problem and my app always crashes because the country flag is nil. Did you find a way around this issue?

Comment: if you can share your code somehow, i may help...
On selected your flag is nil or somewhere else?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether this is a valid solution or not, you could try this

Say let your placeholder be 012345679 what I believe you could do is

- Create a variable to store this placeholder
- Parse this placeholder against the country that the user selects.
- Set the parsed one as the placeholder in the textfield.

Comment: Already tried this, but parser provides me invalid phone number against this string. i tried with "\(country_code)1231234567" and expected a result like "+1 (123) 123-4567". But no

Comment: Could you please specify the country code so that I could check on the sample project

Comment: You can use any country code i tried it for +1, +91, +92 using PhoneNumberKit third party

Comment: I just tried like 
phoneNumberKit.format(phoneNumberKit.parse("123456789", withRegion: "FR", ignoreType: false), toType: .international)

Comment: let me share my code in that case. Please verify that code.

Comment: But I don't know how far it will work since I believe the number of digits may vary depending on the country right

Comment: I edited my question and added code to it. I'm getting exception against that code.

Comment: So try like
 let phoneNumber = try phoneNumberKit.parse("1230123456", withRegion: "FR", ignoreType: false)
Then format that phoneNumber like
let formatedNumber = honeNumberKit.format(phoneNumber, toType: .international)

Comment: Updated the code, but still getting exception. Please let me know if something i'm doing wrong. Check update 2, i edited my question again.

Comment: The error was like the number was not a valid one. If you delete one digit it will work.

Comment: But this cant work for all countries, we can't apply checks on each country, so didn't go with this solution.

Comment: Yup that's what I had said above like I'm not sure how far this solution will work.