# add mask to UITextFile in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to know how can I implement a mask in Swift to format the input in a UITextField in real time as a Telephone number. I was looking for but I've only found complex code, I think it would be more simple. Correct me if I'm wrong.
The desired mask I describe below.

```
000-00-00-00
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want to checkout this pod i've created some while ago:

[TLCustomMask](https://github.com/Edudjr/TLCustomMask)

It is really simple to use.

result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is not that simple. Anyway this question is already answered [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609104/xcode-swift-formatting-text-as-phone-number)

Or you can look for a library in the github such as: [PhoneNumberKit](https://github.com/marmelroy/PhoneNumberKit)

Answer (score 0):

The [InputMask_](https://github.com/RedMadRobot/input-mask-ios) library supports the formatting you'd like to achieve.

Your subject requires some extensive text/cursor watching with lots of edge cases; I'd highly recommend to use a ready solution.